# Symfony 3 Formtype child doesn't return the same block prefix

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-selectors

I need your help.
I have some trouble with 1 entity parent and one entity child. 
The first is for add some new advert and the second is just for edit the advert without changing the date.

AdvertType:

```
class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('title', TextType::class)
                ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('date', DateTimeType::class)
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
        ;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'LH\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'lh_platformbundle_advert';
    }

}
```

and the child AdvertEditType:

```
class AdvertEditType extends AbstractType
{ /** * {@inheritdoc}      */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->remove('date');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return AdvertType::class;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return parent::getBlockPrefix();
    }
 }

}
```

The function **getBlockPrefix()** add on the html/twig view some select id whith the prefix **'lh_platformbundle_advert'** on the AdvertType twig form but when i use the child AdvertEditType to create the form, it has a different blockprefix **'lh_platformbundle_advert_edit'**.

I use a **jquery function** who doesn't working on the edit form cause to the different block Prefix.
Is somebody knows how is it possible to keep the same blockPrefix between the parent and the child, and why symfony change it?
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Form Event to modify the form instead using child form.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('title', TextType::class)
                ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('date', DateTimeType::class)
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
                ->addEventListener(
                    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                    array($this, 'onPreSetData')
                )
        ;

    }

    /**
    * This will change your form on PRE_SET_DATA event
    */
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $advert = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // check if editing entity, remove the field
        if($advert['id']){
            $form->remove('date');
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about form event, here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html